# Summing Numbers in an Array Greater than an Inputted Value

Tags: java, arrays

Need to add all numbers in an array that is greater than an inputted number. The seed is just so the output can be replicated.

Example:

[12,16,45,3,32]

Inputted Value: 30

Output:

77

```
import java.util.*;

    public class SumAbove {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
            int seed = scnr.nextInt();
            Random rand = new Random(seed);


            System.out.println("Enter a positive integer between 1-100 to search above:");
            int minVal = scnr.nextInt();

            int[] arr = new int[rand.nextInt(100)+1];
            for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));


             int sum = 0;
             for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
             if (arr[i]>minVal) {
                    sum += i;
                }
             }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: small mistake in `sum += i;` which should be `sum += arr[i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `sum += i;` you want `sum += arr[i];` (as already noted), you also only need one loop (since you know the minimum before the first loop). Like,

```
int minVal = scnr.nextInt(), sum = 0;
int[] arr = new int[rand.nextInt(100) + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if (arr[i] > minVal) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sum += i` with `sum += arr[i]`.

The variable `i` is just the position. `arr[i]` is the value at that position.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int nums[] = { 12, 16, 45, 3, 32 };
    int value;
    int sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer between 1-100 to search above: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    value = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > value)
            sum = nums[i] + sum;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with streams in Java 8+.

```java
      int nValues = 5;
      int minValue = 1;
      int maxValue = 30;
      Random r = new Random();
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         int[] values = r.ints(nValues, minValue, maxValue + 1).toArray();

         // min to sum is the threshold
         int minToSum = r.nextInt(7) + 10; // between 10 an 16 inclusive


         int sum = Arrays.stream(values).filter(m -> m > minToSum).sum();

         System.out.println("sum = " + sum + " for greater than " + minToSum
               + " : " + Arrays.toString(values));
      }
```

The following output.

```
sum = 65 for values greater than 11 : [2, 10, 14, 23, 28]
sum = 92 for values greater than 10 : [13, 18, 15, 19, 27]
sum = 94 for values greater than 12 : [25, 6, 14, 25, 30]
sum = 54 for values greater than 10 : [14, 8, 14, 26, 5]
sum = 22 for values greater than 15 : [15, 8, 13, 22, 14]
sum = 28 for values greater than 13 : [3, 28, 9, 6, 5]
sum = 87 for values greater than 13 : [5, 18, 25, 21, 23]
sum = 31 for values greater than 13 : [16, 7, 12, 2, 15]
sum = 42 for values greater than 15 : [7, 22, 20, 10, 5]
sum = 40 for values greater than 12 : [2, 2, 13, 27, 9]
```